# How to add text at the end of each line in Vim with specific pattern?

Tags: regex, vim, macvim

my yaml file:

```
colors
-  black
-  white
-  red
-  green
size
-  big
-  small
-  medium
weight
-  100
-  200
-  300
```

...

How can I add ":" to the end of each line that doesn't start with "-  "?

Result should be something like this:

```
colors:
-  black
-  white
-  red
-  green
size:
-  big
-  small
-  medium
weight:
-  100
-  200
-  300
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
:%v/^-/normal A:
```

In the spirit of skinning cats (thanks for bringing some humor to this, romainl :) ),

```
:v/^-/normal A:
:g/^[^-]/s/$/:/
```

Comment: You can drop the `%`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
:v/^-/norm A:
```

Comment: Thank you. I up voted it, but accepted R Sahu's answer, cuz he was first.

Answer (score 3):

Cat skinning is so much fun:

```
:v/^-/s/$/:
:%s/^[^-].*/&:
```